# CSS positioning of images and labels on div

Tags: css, positioning

I'm developing a kind of list where my elements are clickable. I already used [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/SaRnR/)  and now I have this:

[image]

However, now I need to add some more elements (one or two buttons, 1 label, and 1 image) like in the following picture.

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A clickable element (button) inside in a clickable element (link) doesn't look as a great idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/SaRnR/9/ - here you have it :) updated. Put your buttons inside the buttonContainer